# I am trying to get a data from a list of objects

Tags: jquery, json

```
$(function () {
    var info = $('#userInfo').text();
    var empFirstName = info.EmployeeFirstName;

    alert(empFirstName);
    alert(info);

});
```

The info variable contains the below:

```
{"EmployeeID":"123456789","EmployeeLastName":"James","EmployeeFirstName":"Duke"}
```

All i need is how to get the `EmployeeFirstName` from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `.text()` method is returning a string, you wouldn't be able to access the `EmployeeFirstName` property, as it does not yet exist. You will instead need to parse the string, and produce an object:

```js
var info = JSON.parse( $( "#userInfo" ).text() );
var empFirstName = info.EmployeeFirstName;
```

Support for `JSON` may be lacking depending on your desired browser support.